# Not able to run Django website without port 8000(for eg: website.example:8000) using cyberpanel and openlitespeed

Tags: django, hosting, openlitespeed, cyber-panel

I am trying to host website on cyberpanel with openlitespeed server, CentOS operating system. but whenever I am trying to make the project live it is not coming on the specified domain but running only on the `example.com:8000`.

I did all the changes in the `settings.py` file related to project.

Comment: Follow https://openlitespeed.org/kb/python-wsgi-applications/ to set up.

Comment: You haven't provided enough details that anybody can help you solve your issue.  We'd need to see your server configuration files.

Comment: context / {
  type                    appserver
  location                /home/example.com/public_html/
  binPath                 /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lswsgi
  appType                 wsgi
  startupFile             cyberpanel/wsgi.py
  env                     LS_PYTHONBIN=/home/example.com/public_html/bin/python
  env                     PYTHONHOME=/home/example.com/public_html/

Comment: this is my configuration file, that I edited in the vhost configuration in the cyber panel.